# Print random number until stop button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

hello everyone I am trying to write this program where when you click on open vault random numbers will print out until stop is clicked but I am having trouble because I am teaching myself Html/CSS/javascript. I built it this far but the numbers won't print out and I want it to run something like this....please help and thank you in advance.

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

const rndInt = randomIntFromInterval(0, 10000.00)
console.log(rndInt)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>run game </title>
</head>

<body style=" color: black; margin:auto">
  <!-- table border -->
  <div class="borderline">
    <div>
      <h1>$</h1>
      <div class="amount">
        <p id="amount_print" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: green;"></p>
      </div>
      <button class="bail" style="height: 50px; width: 150px; background-color: green" onclick="randomIntFromInterval">OPEN-VAULT</button>
      <button class="bail" style="height: 50px; width: 150px">STOP</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically.

Comment: Just to add on to that, if you're new to js - any time you use iteration make sure your methods end periodically.  So for example in other languages you could (pseudocode) `do { printNumber(); wait(1); bool clicked = checkIfClicked() } until (clicked)` but browsers will consider code "hung" if a function takes too long to return, so you need to use setInterval or setTimeout (or requestAnimationFrame if it needs to run really often) to return control to the browser in between iterations of your code.

Comment: Also, if you're new to html and doing it in a professional setting.... don't use tables unless the data is tabular.  You can accomplish the same thing with divs and flex or grid css attributes, or even display: table.  It's an accessibility thing (as accessibility technologies will treat it as tabular data regardless of what it looks like), and it's also easier to refactor/work with and generates less structure usually.  Just takes a bit to get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone tbh idk much of these functions but ill do a little research on it to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to put `()` after the function name in the `onclick` attribute to call the function.
- Calling `randomIntFromInterval()` doesn't display anything. You need to call a function that displays the result of the function.
- Use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically, and `clearInterval()` to stop this.

I've used `setInterval()` to run a function that puts the random number into the `amount_print` element.

```js
let interval;

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(() => amount_print.innerText = randomIntFromInterval(0, 10000), 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>run game </title>
</head>

<body style=" color: black; margin:auto">
  <!-- table border -->
  <div class="borderline">
    <div>
      <h1>$</h1>
      <div class="amount">
        <p id="amount_print" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: green;"></p>
      </div>
      <button class="bail" style="height: 50px; width: 150px; background-color: green" onclick="start()">OPEN-VAULT</button>
      <button class="bail" style="height: 50px; width: 150px" onclick="stop()">STOP</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```